# How to retrieve a class with complex object property so that the prop is not null - EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework

How can I query db with entity framework that the List complex property is not null ? I always get it null if I call **context.Media** ... I only managed to get the "Media" object with all properties with data filled with the help of join and a new DTO class. And it is very inconvenient.

```
public class Media
{
   //other properties
    public List<URL> MediaRSSURL { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable Lazy Loading declare the Navigation Property like this:

```
public class Media
{
    //other properties
    public virtual ICollection<URL> MediaRSSURL { get; } = new HashSet<URL>();
}
```

Otherwise EF can't replace the property getter with a Lazy Loading one in a dynamic proxy object.